# SQL Cursor execution quandry

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, dynamic-sql

I have a Stored Procedure that is using dynamic sql to build its complex query for a report. At one point, it is calling `exec(@sql)` right before opening the cursor... I believe this is a mistake and the `exec(@sql)` command can be removed as it is executing individually and not needed to use the cursor...

Am I right? Here's a snippet:

```
-- before this it's just doing string concatenation
SET @sql = N'DECLARE cc CURSOR STATIC FOR ' + @sql 
exec(@Sql) --<-- is this needed here?
OPEN cc
```

Doesn't opening the cursor effectively run the SQL inside the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is needed.

The `@sql` variable is prepended with the `CURSOR` declaration script just before the `EXEC(@sql)` line.  It is done this way because you cannot declare a cursor with the following:

```
DECLARE cc CURSOR STATIC FOR EXECUTE(@sql)
```

You can't declare a `CURSOR FOR` an exec.

This was written this way to get around that by prepending the `CURSOR` declare statement to the dynamic SQL.  The original author wasn't trying to execute it within the body of a `CURSOR`, but rather create a `CURSOR` for the result set of the dynamic SQL that was written.

So, yes, this is needed.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Not used to the wonky dynamic sql stuff. Haven't seen it in years. This is an older system.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I would advise against using cursors or dynamic sql unless absolutely necessary, you need to include all of your cursor manipulation (and any other sql that operates on the same dataset) inside the @sql variable.  Otherwise, you're running two entirely separate sql commands.

For example:

```
SET @sql = N'DECLARE cc CURSOR STATIC FOR ' + @sql 
@sql = @sql + 'OPEN cc'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I don't understand, is that a 'yes' or a 'no'? I'm assuming you mean, 'yes it's a duplicate unnecessary line' pertaining to the 'exec(@sql)'

Comment: Opening a cursor does execute the sql inside the cursor, but you still need to fetch the records and do whatever other processing you want, which is NOT included in the cursor's code.  But without seeing all of your code, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  I think you may be on the wrong track.

Comment: Understood (and you have my sympathy) - but without seeing the code, I still can't tell what you're trying to do.